XERO API InvoiceNumber causing Error Message: 400 Bad Request "{\r\n \"ErrorNumber\": 10
When I POST and ACCPAY invoice it works perfectly when I don't include the InvoiceNumber.
When I include the Invoiceumber eg 12345 or ABCDE I have errors. I am only sending ASCII characters per documentation extract below.
ERROR
XERO API InvoiceNumber causing Error Message: 400 Bad Request "{\r\n  \"ErrorNumber\": 10

Screenshot from docs:
InvoiceNumber   ACCREC – Unique alpha numeric code identifying invoice (printable ASCII characters only)
ACCPAY – non-unique alpha numeric code identifying invoice (printable ASCII characters only). This value will also display as Reference in the UI.

Any help appriciated.
Added and remove InvoiceNumber field to identify the issue

Is it a new invoice? If so, does it work if you use PUT instead of POST?
